# run daemon process and run next process

Tags: process, background-process

I have a shell script and it has 3 program:

```
#!/bin/bash
x
y
z
```

each of above programs is binary and have to run in order.
program `y` is a daemon. When bash run `x`, it's okey and when `y` is running, `z` can't run.
I run y such as `nohup y &` but `z` couldn't run.

How can I run `z` after `y` such as non-blocking programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
x
y > /dev/null &
z
```